# error "illegal option --t" occus when import OSM map into postgis [windows environment]

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis

I want to import OSM map into postgis, so used the following command in windows cmd console:

```
osm2pgsql -U postgres -d osm -hstore -s _S ./default.style ./xxxx.osm
```

But  "illegal option --t" error occus:
osm2pgsql illegal option --t
Usage error.

I don't know what's the meaning of "illegal option --t" and don't know how to handle it.
I've looked at several articles but haven't find any answer.
thanks.

p.s I've installed postgis 2.1.7 and postgresql 9.4 and hstore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least 2 mistakes in your command `-hstore` instead of `--hstore` and `_S` instead of `-S` .

So:

```
osm2pgsql -U postgres -d osm --hstore -s -S ./default.style ./xxxx.osm
```

Comment: it works. Thank you. i'm just start use postgis so not fimilar with the commands.